# Tomcat server not finding representations of endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle

I am creating gradle Spring MVC project without Spring-Boot, and for some reason when I run Tomcat server doesn't see the endpoint in my controller class.

My controller is very simple just to test if it works:

```
@RestController
public class CertificateController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getAllCertificates() {
        return "try";
    }
}
```

My Spring Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.epam.esm")
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

My Initializer class:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ApplicationConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

The project itself is multi-module: API module for application configuration and controllers and CORE module for program logic which is currently empty.

To the server, I give the root project artifact. Root project gradle.build:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

subprojects {
    project(':api') {
        apply plugin: 'application'
        apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'war'
    }

    project(':core') {
        apply plugin: 'java'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    java {
        sourceCompatibility(11)
        targetCompatibility(11)
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.15'
        implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.15'
        implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.15'
        implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.15'

        implementation 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:3.0.13.RELEASE'

        implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'

        implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4'
        implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.3.2'

        implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.16.0'

        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
        testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.1.0'
        testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.148'
    }
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The server loads fine but when I try to access the endpoint it says:

```
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Comment: And how are you bootstrapping your Spring application? Where is your class registering the `DispatcherServlet` and web configuration? In short there is too little (relevant) information in your question to answer this.

Comment: I edited my question and added Config and Initializer classes.

Comment: Don't autowire the `ApplicationContext` into the configuration, the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` is `ApplicationContextAware` and it will be automatically injected anyway. You also appear to be missing an `@EnableWebMvc` .

Comment: Another thing is you are using `@RestController` but your configuration makes me wonder if you intended to use `@Controller` as you are using Thymeleaf and don't have any other view related library in your dependencies, nor a serialization one like Jackson or Gson.

Comment: I added ```@EnableWebMvc``` but that didn't help.
I also had other setups for both Config and Initializer classes before but that didn't work, so I followed this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4iCQYoI4Cs 
But even though I changed it still doesn't find the endpoint.

Comment: As stated **what** are you trying to return? A view (as hinted on by your configuration) or the text `try`. As for the first to work you need `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`, for the latter you would need to add something like `Jackson` to your dependencies.

Comment: For this testing controller, I only return text, later in the program, I will return ResponceEntity.

Comment: As for the view, I cannot get it to return even if I change annotation to ```@Controller```

Comment: But you are requesting HTML (judging from the exception). Another thing which tomcat version are you deploying the application on? I do assume you actually build the application and deployed it? For the view you would need a `try.html` in your view directory.

Comment: I use tomcat 9.0.54, I add the war(exploded) artifact to the deployment section of server configurations.

Comment: Then it must be something you aren't explaining here. What you have should work, if it doesn't there is something that isn't in here. one thing is that the `servlet-api` dependency should have a different scope, but I doubt that that is the issue. Enable DEBUG logging, issue a request and figure out what is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241654/discussion-between-judita-and-m-deinum).

Comment: And if I added something like this implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.1'  would this be enough to return text or other stuff?

Comment: That depends on what content-type you are actually requesting and your browser is accepting. But as I stated, enable DEBUG logging and see what is going on when the request gets handled.